# Make ASP.Net Core Web API endpoint to consume any data type as payload

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-webapi

I am creating an API endpoint that can receive any kind of data type but I am not sure how to specify that in my method

I currently have the following

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string? req = null)
 {
   .......
 }
```

I want to be able to receive any type of POST request payload because the request comes from different sources in different formats.
I can work on the request within the method to convert it to other data types as desired after it has been received

Thank you

Comment: Please refer to [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/sep/14/accepting-raw-request-body-content-in-aspnet-core-api-controllers) for some suggestions on how to accept raw data in your controller actions.

Comment: Have you try to custom formatter in your Project? Please refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the endpoint accept any type of input parameter, the following piece of code can do it

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] object? request = null)
 {
  //Other code to validate the request and convert to any desired type of object
  ...
 }
```

With this, the endpoint can receive any type of object and process it according to the other parts of the code

I hope this helps someone